# Parallel Webclient

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, webclient

I have a function with is basically divided in two subfunctions.

```
html=RetriveHTML(int index);
returnColection = RegexProcess(html, index);
```

What is the best way to speed up this process by optimizing the RetrieveHTML paralelization?

Usually I call this with up to 20000 indexes.
The first subfuntcion is network dependent (GET several URLs HTML from one server using webclient.downloadstring) and second subfunction is CPU mainly.

I am lost in the Parallel foreach and Tasks(continue with, continueall, fromasync) world and I am having troubles to come to a solution. I first tried Parallel foreach for its simplicity but I found that its performance namely the network I/O degrades over successive calls (1st loop is fast the others become slow). The solution would free the html objects as they are processed since they are many and big. I am using .net 4.0...

Comment: Many web servers will limit the number of connections allowed by a client concurrently.  Are you hitting that limit?

Comment: TPL is not good at guessing the right number of threads for IO operations like downloading. Have you tried specifying the degree of parallelism?

Comment: @Koerner No because the cycle is always the same. For some reason it takes more time the second time it runs.

Comment: @svick Yes, I have set the maximum concurrency to the number of allowed connections.
What other alternatives are there to using the Paralel foreach that should be used for this?

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see if the web server is coming back slower or if it is responding fine, but your code is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try the code below

```
private Regex _regex= new Regex("net");

        private void ProcessInParallell()
        {
           Uri[] resourceUri = new Uri[]{new Uri("http://www.microsoft.com"),new Uri( "http://www.google.com"),new Uri( "http://www.amazon.com") };


            //1. Stage 1: Download HTML

            //Use the blocking collection for concurrent tasks
            BlockingCollection<string> htmlDataList = new BlockingCollection<string>();

            Parallel.For(0, resourceUri.Length , index =>
                {   var html = RetrieveHTML(resourceUri[index]);

                    htmlDataList.TryAdd(html);

                    //If we reach to the last index, signal the completion
                    if (index == (resourceUri.Length - 1))
                    {   
                        htmlDataList.CompleteAdding();
                    }

                });


            //2. Get matches

            //This concurrent bags will be used to store the result of the matching stage
            ConcurrentBag<string> matchedHtml = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

            IList<Task> processingTasks  = new List<Task>();

            //Enumerate through each downloaded HTML document
            foreach (var html  in htmlDataList.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                //Create a new task to match the downloaded HTML
              var task=   Task.Factory.StartNew((data) =>
                    {
                        var downloadedHtml = data as string;
                        if(downloadedHtml ==null)
                            return;

                        if (_regex.IsMatch(downloadedHtml))
                        {

                            matchedHtml.Add(downloadedHtml);
                        }

                    }, 
                     html  
                    );

                //Add the task to the waiting list
                processingTasks.Add(task);

            }

            //wait for the all tasks to complete
            Task.WaitAll(processingTasks.ToArray());



            foreach (var html in matchedHtml)
            {
                //Do something with the matched result    

            }




        }

        private string  RetrieveHTML(Uri uri)
        {
           using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
           {
               //set this to null if there is no proxy
               webClient.Proxy = null;

               byte[] data =webClient.DownloadData(uri);

               return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the repply. But would not this use too much memory if many/long html files are downloaded?

Comment: I realized that if the downloaded contents are big, it would consume a lot of memory. Hence you'd better to chunk the work load. Cheers